# How to find all function in runthime by Telescope

Tags: neovim

i'm using a lot of plugins in neovim, for each plugin , we have a lot of function

#### How can i grep all function by telescope

```
:Telescope find_call
```

then run this function if possible

Comment: You should try to create your own solution: Check [this readme section](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim#api) about how to create your own finders and pickers, try to create one using [`:h :function`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Afunction) to get the list of available functions and if what you try doesn't work you will have some code to share in your question so people can help you fixing your code rather than creating a solution from scratch for your.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It's very difficult for me to understand your question. I have some clarifying questions: please [edit] to add the information. You write "How can i grep all function by telescope [sic]"—does this mean "How can I find all the functions related to the Telescope plugin?" or "How do I use the Telescope plugin to find functions?"? What is the `:Telescope` command/where does it come from? You write "then run this function if possible"—what function?